# Why would a DOM element not exist when I've just created it?

Tags: javascript, dom

The following javascript is run onload:

```
var shop_checkout = {
    setup: function() {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = '/public/styles/images/confirm_payment.png';
        img.id  = 'confirm_payment';
        img.alt = 'Confirm Payment: submit order and charge my card';
        var span = app.get('submit_checkout');
        console.log('found the span');
        span.innerHTML = '';
        console.log('emptied the span');
        span.appendChild(img);
        console.log('appended the image');
        img.onclick = shop_checkout.onsubmit;
        console.log('set the onclick');
    },
    onsubmit: function() {
        // irrelevant
    },
    submitted: function() {
        // irrelevant
    },
    oncheckout: function(json, status) {
        // irrelevant
    }
};

app.onload(shop_checkout.setup);
```

(`app.onload()` is a simple function which builds up a list of functions to fire on load, and `app.get()` is a simple shortcut for `document.getElementById()`. This is shown at the bottom.)

Most of the time, this works grand. Now and again, it gets as far as emptying the span, but fails to append the image. The error message produced is: “Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8”.

Now, [DOM Exception 8](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-dom-20120105/#dom-domexception-not_found_err) is a not found error, which suggests that the `img` doesn’t exist, even though I created it just a couple of lines previously. What could be going on here?

I’m guessing that the `img` DOM element doesn’t necessarily exist, even though the variable referring to it does exist. Is that right? And what can I do about it?

Here's the app code:

```
var app = {
    get: function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    },
    onload: function(func) {
        // http://www.dustindiaz.com/top-ten-javascript/
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload !== 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function() {
                if (oldonload) {
                    oldonload();
                }
                func();
            };
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Just curious: why aren't you using a cross-browser library (any one will do)?

Comment: Because there really shouldn't be any need for a library for something as simple as this, should there? What code do you see which is browser-incompatible?

Comment: Does app.onload call the passed function with ()?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind: Is the `img` element attached to the DOM _after_ the image is delivered over the wire?

Comment: I've thrown `app` in as a supplement, @mplungjan.

Comment: @Jasen. Yes. No. I don't know. That could be the problem. And that could be why it behaves inconsistently. I don't pause to check that the image has been downloaded before calling `appendChild()`. Nor am I sure how I could.

Comment: If load latency is the issue you could try pre-caching or using css instead.

Comment: @MattBall: He is using a library. The most cross-browser compatible out there (yes, even works on IE5). He's using an inlined version of vapor.js

Comment: This is an interesting bug. You shouldn't need to wait for the image to load before appending. That's how it's supposed to work. Have you tried the `Image()` constructor instead of `document.createElement()`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `<span>` element never gets attached to the DOM. You can only find things by id if they descend from the document (`<html>`).

Make sure to append the `<span>` to the document before you try to find anything that gets attached to it (directly or to descendants).

Answer (score 0):

One reason is related to elements that have asynchronous data. Or elements that are added to the DOM after the document is loaded.
In jQuery, the following command can be used

```
$ ('element').ready (readyFn);
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

And in Angular , element change event can be useful